# Why redirect to https got log out?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, apache2.4

I configured default-ssl.conf in apache2.4(use servlet as container) on ubuntu 14.04 to use https which is working, but when I redirect from http to https, it log me out, I think all the security/principle in session with session.setAttribute(). My login info stored in session not cookie.

Any idea what's wrong?

Here is a line in log file:

```
[Mon Apr 10 03:45:00.158038 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 56553:tid  140523494872832] AH02032: Hostname 13.93.221.169_ provided via SNI and hostname 13.93.221.169\r provided via HTTP are different
```

Thanks!
Oneofkind

Answer (score 0):

Normally modern servers do not accept http cookie for https connection for security reason, so session valid in http won't works in https, you need to make your login process also under https

Comment: Thanks, my login is in java, then stored it in session, so how to cross session/context to https? @number5

Comment: @Oneofkind it almost impossible to make session cross http/https now. better way is to force https everywhere. For secure cookie, check out https://geekflare.com/secure-cookie-flag-in-tomcat/

Comment: @Oneofkind that's different question, I have no idea about that. Better create another question